# How can I change the language of dynamic text in a SWF using flashvars?

Tags: flash, embed, translation, swfobject

I have a SWF with text embedded from an external .txt file. Is there a way I can have a different file used as the text source through the embedcode (swfObject) depending on the language?

**Here is my current actionscript:**

```
myData = new LoadVars();
myData.onLoad = function() {
text_clips.project_title.text = this.projecttitle1;
};
myData.load("translatetext.txt");

var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
loader.loadClip(_level0.projectimage1,pic1.image_holder);
```

**This is the content of translatetext.txt:**

```
projecttitle1=This is my translatable text
```

**This is the embed code I'm using:**

```
<div>
            <object width="960" height="275" id="rvFlashcontent">
<param name="movie" value="lang_test_3.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="flashvars" value="projectimage1=flashimages/testimage.jpg" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="lang_test_3.swf" width="960" height="275">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="flashvars" value="projectimage1=flashimages/testimage.jpg" />
<!--<![endif]-->
<h1>Alt Content</h1>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
    </div>
```

What I want to do is add a Flashvars parameter to name the file to load, so I can change the language:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="projectimage1=flashimages/image.jpg&projecttext=textfrench.txt" />
```

There are four languages needed so far, but this will grow so it needs to be flexible enough to let the developers add languages without getting a new SWF each time. Thanks in advance all!

[Files for this question available here...](http://db.tt/WzXift)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking how to access flashvars or how to handle multiple languages, but assuming it's the former, you can get at flashvars like so:

```
protected function init():void
{
    var flashvars:Object = LoaderInfo(root.loaderInfo).parameters;
    var myDataLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    myDataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoadComplete);
    myDataLoader.load(new URLRequest(flashvars.projecttext));
}

protected function onDataLoadComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var myDataLoader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
    var myData:Object = myDataLoader.data;
    // now you can do whatever you want with the contents of the file (i.e. myData)
}
```

== Edit ==

You need to add an event listener that will fire when the load is complete. I've edited my pseudo code above as an example...

Comment: Thanks. I can get at the flashvars text, but really I want to feed the filename, and get the actual text from the file, not the embed code. 

http://skitch.com/birdie/dn21a/flash-dynamic-lang-1

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888023/reading-the-text-file-line-by-line-and-push-to-an-array-in-as3

It might be just what you're looking for. Good Luck!