# Read file and put it in to array?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Please help me, I have problem with my program.
I'm newbie of flash AS3.0. 
I want to read filetext (.txt) and put it in to array.
here is my sample text from my file.

> 22 33
>
> 11 22
>
> 45 56

How can I read file and put it in to array like a[0] = 22 a[1] = 33 a[4]=11 ....
or I should use 2 dimension array ? Is flash AS3.0 has 2 dimension array ?

please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888023/reading-the-text-file-line-by-line-and-push-to-an-array-in-as3, then use split to break the line into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var toLoad:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.txt");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(toLoad);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded, false, 0, true);

function loaded(evt:Event):void
{
    var txtData:String = evt.currentTarget.data;
    txtData = txtData.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    txtData = txtData.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    txtData = txtData.replace(/\s+$/, '')
    var textAr:Array = txtData.split(" ");
    trace(textAr.toString());
}
```

The RegEx was sourced from [Grant Skinner's](http://www.gskinner.com) [StringUtils](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/04/free_extension.html).

Comment: There are error.
"Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error."

Comment: Did you change the URL to reflect your .txt file name? I also added an extra line to trim whitespace before the string too.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I forget to save file flash and It works !! Thank you

Errr If I want to output array[10]. I must use "trace(textAr[9]);" right ?

Comment: Yes, the tenth item in an array is in fact [9], as they begin at 0.

Comment: You should accept Matt's answer if your  question was solved.