# Storing a large string in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

My game stores levels in large strings. Not very long, the length is about half my desktop on a 1080p screen. Flash can handle it fine, but when I do something like

```
var levels:Array = ["Large String
gets broken up because of the len
gth"];
```

Flash IDE tells me that I will need to end the string literal before a new line. I can't, since it's too long. (For the IDE, not flash enviroment)

How should I store the string?

Comment: You can include any txt file inside of your project and read it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888023/reading-the-text-file-line-by-line-and-push-to-an-array-in-as3

Comment: @AutoCoder: Thanks, but this is a game that will be hosted on servers beyond my control. I also don't like to buy hosting space just to deliver identical strings..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also embed the text files in your app in much the same way you would embed a Bitmap.

```
[Embed(source='test.txt', mimeType='application/octet-stream')]
private var TextData:Class;

...

var thing:String = new TextData();
trace(thing);
```

Note: a mimeType of 'text/plain' does not go down well with the compiler hence the octet-stream.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for. Does this work for flash IDE or just flashdevelop? (on my phone here, can't try)

Comment: This should work in the Adobe CS Flash Pro. Although I believe, from memory, that it will give you a message about needing to use the Flex SDK for embeds or similar but then will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this :

```
private var myString:String = ( <![CDATA[

Large String
gets broken up because of the len
gth

]]> ).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept you if there's no more elegant solutions (Is it possible to compile a text file inside?)

Comment: What do you mean 'compile a text file inside'?

Comment: If you mean embed a text file, then it is. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

either do it like AutoCoder said in his comment

> You can include any txt file inside of your project and read it -  [Reading the text file line by line and push to an array in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888023/reading-the-text-file-line-by-line-and-push-to-an-array-in-as3)

Or,

```
var levels:Array = ["Large String" + 
    "gets broken up because of the len" +
    "gth", 

    "Another Large String" + 
    "gets broken up because of the len" +
    "gth"
];
```

This will give you an array like:

```
["Large String gets broken up because of the length", "Another Large String gets broken up because of the length"]
```

Alternatively, put the entire string on one line (without any line breaks). It now looks as if you are putting in line breaks to make the string more readable.

Comment: Nope, mine is too long. I have no line breaks, it's the limit of flash ide

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You should use external ".txt" file and load it by URLLoader ?

It always make game more dynamic .